# Groupby contains two specific values - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm aiming to return rows in a pandas df that contain two specific values grouped by a separate column. Using below, I'm grouping by `Num` and aiming to return rows where `B` is present but not `A` for each unique group.

If neither `A` nor `B` is assigned to a grouped value then continue. I only want to return the rows where `B` is present but not `A`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({      
    'Num' : [1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4],
    'Label' : ['X','Y','X','B','B','B','A','B','B','A','B','X'],          
   })

df = df.loc[(df['Label'] == 'A') | (df['Label'] == 'B')]
df = df.groupby('Num').filter(lambda x: any(x['Label'] == 'A'))
df = df.groupby('Num').filter(lambda x: any(x['Label'] == 'B'))
```

intended output:

```
    Num Label  
2     2     B      
3     2     B  
4     2     B  
5     2     B
```

Comment: kindly fix your data, as there is no `Item` column in the source dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter if all values per groups are `B` by [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html):

```
df1 = df.loc[(df['Label'] == 'A') | (df['Label'] == 'B')]
df1 = df1[(df1['Label'] == 'B').groupby(df1['Num']).transform('all')]
print (df1)
   Num Label
3    2     B
4    2     B
5    2     B
```

If need fitler original column `Num` use:

```
df = df[df['Num'].isin(df1['Num'])]
print (df)
   Num Label
2    2     X
3    2     B
4    2     B
5    2     B
```

Another approach is filter by [`numpy.setdiff1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html):

```
num = np.setdiff1d(df.loc[(df['Label'] == 'B'), 'Num'],
                   df.loc[(df['Label'] == 'A'), 'Num'])

df = df[df['Num'].isin(num)]
print (df)
   Num Label
2    2     X
3    2     B
4    2     B
5    2     B
```

Comment: OP output has four rows